# The client noticed that the server is not a supported distribution of Elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, loopback4

I'm using @elastic/elasticsearch version ^7.5.0 and Node 10.24.1 with loopback 4 and loopback-connector-esv6. Everything worked fine, until I redeploy my backend and since then I'm getting the following error:

The client noticed that the server is not a supported distribution of Elasticsearch

Comment: downgrade your Elasticsearch client version to <v7.14.0

Comment: "@loopback/authorization": "~0.5.4",
    "@loopback/core": "~2.2.0",
    "@loopback/cron": "~0.2.10",
    "@loopback/openapi-v3": "~3.1.1",
    "@loopback/repository": "~2.0.2",
    "@loopback/rest": "~3.1.0",
    "@loopback/rest-explorer": "~2.0.2", 
    "loopback-connector-esv6": "2.0.0",
    "loopback-connector-mysql": "~5.4.2",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@elastic/elasticsearch": "~7.5.0",
    "@types/elasticsearch": "~5.0.36",
    "@types/node": "~10.17.17",
  }

Comment: @boolfalse I didn't understand I have a fixed version on my package.json

Comment: For future reference, this question has also been referenced elsewhere: https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback-connector-elastic-search/issues/140